# how to overcome filetime() error in typo3

Tags: typo3

> (1/1) #1476107295 TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Exception PHP Warning:
>   filemtime(): stat failed for
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/typonew/public/fileadmin/templates/main_1_column_with_menu.html
>   in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/typonew/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/View/TemplatePaths.php
>   line 625

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the file `fileadmin/templates/main_1_column_with_menu.html`doesn't exist. Create the file, check the file permission or change the path in your configuration.